# Meaning of phrase in Hannukah song

Tags: hebrew, chanuka, song-poetry

I'm having trouble understanding the concluding phrase in the famous Hannukah song O Hannukah, which is על הנפלאות אשר חללו המכבים.  What root is חללו and what is its meaning here?  How to translate the phrase?

Comment: Are you sure its חללו? I think it would make sense if it is הללו meaning "on the wonders that the Maccabim praised"

Comment: The line is heresy. The verb לחולל means "to generate" (cite: Google translate). Maccabees do not chas veshalom generate miracles.

Comment: https://www.tzohar.org.il/?p=2742

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh. That must be why I learned the lyric as אשר חולל ה' למכבים, "that G-d wrought for the Maccabees".

Comment: @dov They say it means accomplished. Anyway it is not in any of  the original yiddish versions.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_Chanukah#  The only big change is in the last line - whereas the original calls to praise God for the miracles he performed, the Hebrew one praises the miracles and wonders performed by the Maccabees. This reflects the anti-religious polemic of early Zionism, evident in many other Israeli Chanukah songs.

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not heresy, or at least not heretical in terms of attributing mystical powers solely to humans. The original version of the song was written from a secular perspective, not that that in itself is evidence of non-heresy, but the idea was never that the the נפלאות are miraculous, supernatural events, but that they were wonderous and impressive events, as one would describe other impressive military victories based on ingenious strategies and such. Later, religious people changed that particular line to what ezra wrote.

Comment: @Harel a solely secular perspective to history is itself heresy (aka deism)

Comment: @DoubleAA Well sure, but you understood the line itself as saying the Maccabees did actual supernatural miracles. That's not what the line is saying. It's saying that they accomplished great and wonderous things, not miracles. Now that I think about it, it wouldn't make sense to write an anti-religious song yet attribute supernatural powers to the song's subject. The whole intent of the song is to say that nothing supernatural happened, it was all thanks to great strategy, physical strength, determination, courage, etc.

Comment: @Harel the point is it's heresy mimanafshach. Either deism or some sort of shittuf (?).

Comment: @DoubleAA I dunno...I just don't think we need nor should add more faults to the anti-religious Zionists. Sure, in context, the line is heretical, but without the context, when examining just line itself (which is what we're doing here), it's not.

Comment: @Harel Heresy is not a fault I'm adding to anti-religious groups.

Comment: @DoubleAA I know you're not. I meant just about this specific line.

Comment: @Harel you're basically saying if we reinterpret the words from what the authors intended it's not technically literally heresy. This is like arguing for some forced reinterpretation of Jingle Bells as a Hanukkah song. Sure if you intend the right things it might not get you makkot arbaim, but it certainly would get you makkat mardut

Answer (score 1):

According to [Milog](https://milog.co.il/%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9C/e_54539), the root of חוללו is חי"ל, which is a root that is related to courage and strength. For example, Rabbi Yochanan famously said to Reish Lakish: "חילך לאורייתא - Your strength is fit for Torah study." ([Bava Metzia 84a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.84a.12?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

The song comes to praise the Maccabees for the wonderous things they did through their strength. @ezra mentioned "wrought" as the translation for the religious version of the line, "אשר חולל ה' למכבים" - that sounds like a good translation to me for here as well, as they wrought wonderous things [through their strength].